# How to know when template from Meteor package has finished rendering

Tags: meteor, rendering

Is there an event/callback that could be used to monitor and run code just after a template from a third-party package has finished rendering?
This is because I found that some packages render they content shortly after my other templates render and I would like to able to run code just after each one render. But if third-packages have their own subscriptions then I can't use the onReady callback that I use for my own subscriptions...
So, does anyone know a simple way to do this?

Comment: Search the name of the template in the package source code and try using `Template.thirdPartyTemplate.onRendered` ?

Comment: That's it! Thank you. I was using the name of another template that included the specific template that I wanted to manipulate and that's why it was rendered before its "son" and because of that I couldn't grab the contents I wanted because they were not rendered yet...PS: as this is in fact the answer don't you want to make it an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I was unsure about this direction, made it an answer now, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the `onRendered` template lifecycle event on the specific third party package template you want to track being rendered.

```
Template.packageTemplate.onRendered(function(){
  //
});
```

Calling `onRendered` on a parent template that includes the package template won't work because it will trigger BEFORE its child package template own rendered event.